# Number of stages when processing RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I was doing a quiz with the following question:

*How many stages are there in this code?*

```
val unhcrRDD = sc.textFile("path/to/file/file.csv").map(x=>x.split(","))
val country = unhcrRDD.map(x=>(x(0), x(3))
country.take(10)
```

I assumed that there are 3 stages(one when the text file is read, one when the lines are split by commas and one when the fields 0 and 3 are selected).

However, the answer is:

*There is only one stage even though there are more RDDs.Data is not transferred between the parent and the RDD, so the RDDs are collapsed into one stage.*

What does this mean?
How can you have only one stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New stage is only then shuffle is done, so i.e. when doing reduceByKey or join between few RDDs.

In your case you've got only `map`, which can be run without shuffling data between nodes.

You can enter Spark Web UI, there you'll have all stages on image
[image: Spark DAG visualisation]